# Haskell restricting integer values via enumeration

Tags: haskell, types, type-constructor

I want to do something like this:

`data Bit = 0 | 1`

But since the right hand side has to be a valid data constructor (?) I would have to use something like

`data Bit = Zero | One`

This isn't particularly good since I want to use the actual values 0 and 1. What's the best solution to my conundrum?

Comment: Why in particular do you want to use the actual values?

Comment: Well I'd get a lot of bit operations for free. But this is also an example. What if I wanted the numbers 0 - 7 for weekdays?

Comment: `Bool` comes with `and`, `or`.  If you want something more advanced, you can make any type an instance of the `bits` class.  As for days of the weeks, I'd personally choose `data Days = Sunday | Monday | ....`

Comment: Your days of the week are not Z mod 7, ~~which is what I was trying to get at.~~ Edit: Actually no I wasn't, sorry!, I simply wanted to be able to use 0 and 1 in calculations but I want a terse way of prevent any Int input.

Comment: If you wanted a numeric type that's Z mod n, you really should have said so in the first place.

Comment: What I am trying to explain is that the "Haskell"-ey way to get all this functionality you want is to use classes, and that there are many existing classes that already do this for you (like `Bits`).  Sure, the constructors are verbose (although don't have to be, see Daniel's `O | I` example below), but this doesn't matter, as the compiler is going to strip this all, and probably treat these as 0 and 1 anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might enjoy this cheeky `Num` instance I wrote some time ago:

```
instance Num Bool where
    (+) = (/=)
    (*) = (&&)
    negate = id
    abs = id
    signum = id
    fromInteger = odd
```

For example, in ghci:

```
> (3 + 5) * 6 :: Bool
False
```

You should be able to use something similar, suitably modified to support your `data Bit = O | I` rather than `data Bool = False | True`.